# exclude NULL from JsonArray while de-serializing json

Tags: java, spring-boot, gson

I receive an invalid json (extra comma in the end of the list) in request body, which is being successfully deserialized by GSON library. On inspection I see that GSON is inserting a NULL object in the end.

```
{
    "content": "Test 2",
    "timestamp": 1494311947530,
    "entities": [
        {"name": "entity1"},
        {"name": "entity2"},
        {"name": "entity3"},
        {"name": "entity4"},
        {"name": "entity5"},
    ]
}
```

Is there a way by which I can either instruct GSON not to accept invalid json or remove NULL objects from JsonArray.

I have tried registering type adapter for Set.class but I can't proceed further with this solution as it is not possible to get `Type` of the parameterized object.

```
public class RemoveNullCollectionSerializer<T> implements JsonDeserializer<Set<T>> {
    @Override
    public Set<T> deserialize(JsonElement jsonElement, Type type, JsonDeserializationContext context) throws JsonParseException {
        JsonArray elements = jsonElement.getAsJsonArray();

        Set<T> result = new HashSet();
        for (JsonElement element : elements) {
            if (element.isJsonNull()) continue;

            T value = (T) context.deserialize(element, Object.class);
            result.add(value);
        }
        return result;
    }
}
```

I'm trying not to register custom adapters as there are a lot of models in the project and each will require one adapter, which will be a big task.

Comment: It may be possible to remove invalid commas from the serialised string using regular expressions. I'm afraid I don't know the exact syntax though.

Comment: Is the json coming from an API or something? Just trying to figure out how you are receiving invalid json. I don't know of any built-in functions in Gson that allow you to skip null values (except for custom deserializers), however, Genson (https://owlike.github.io/genson/) is very similar in how it works, but it actually *does* allow you to skip null values.

Comment: This is part of a public api that is exposed to users. The json was received from a user application due to a bug in his application, which caused the API endpoint to throw NPE. The service is highly dependent on GSON, so it is a bit difficult to replace it with Genson.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm sorry but Gson seems not be able to do this. There's a special mode in Gson instructing it to work in "lenient" mode -- this is why you're getting a `null`  element in the result collection. The lenient mode tells Gson ignore some soft invalid JSON issues, one of them is reading trailing array elements and object properties. If you take a look at `CollectionTypeAdapterFactory` that actually is responsible for collections [read](https://github.com/google/gson/blob/master/gson/src/main/java/com/google/gson/internal/bind/CollectionTypeAdapterFactory.java#L73), you see:

```java
@Override public Collection<E> read(JsonReader in) throws IOException {
  if (in.peek() == JsonToken.NULL) {
    in.nextNull();
    return null;
  }

  Collection<E> collection = constructor.construct();
  in.beginArray();
  while (in.hasNext()) {
    E instance = elementTypeAdapter.read(in);
    collection.add(instance);
  }
  in.endArray();
  return collection;
}
```

As you can see, an element `instance` is read and **always** added to the result collection. The `elementTypeAdapter.read` may fail in non-lenient mode, but this means that the object will not be constructed totally. You can check it like this:

```java
private static final Gson gson = new GsonBuilder()
        .registerTypeAdapterFactory(new TypeAdapterFactory() {
            @Override
            public <T> TypeAdapter<T> create(final Gson gson, final TypeToken<T> typeToken) {
                if ( !Collection.class.isAssignableFrom(typeToken.getRawType()) ) {
                    return null;
                }
                final TypeAdapter<T> delegateAdapter = gson.getDelegateAdapter(this, typeToken);
                return new TypeAdapter<T>() {
                    @Override
                    public void write(final JsonWriter out, final T value)
                            throws IOException {
                        delegateAdapter.write(out, value);
                    }

                    @Override
                    public T read(final JsonReader in)
                            throws IOException {
                        final boolean wasLenient = in.isLenient();
                        try {
                            in.setLenient(false);
                            return delegateAdapter.read(in);
                        } finally {
                            in.setLenient(wasLenient);
                        }
                    }
                };
            }
        })
        .create();
```

Note that the `read` method disables the lenient mode temporarily and then restores it back. The code above would cause

> Use JsonReader.setLenient(true) to accept malformed JSON at line 20 column 3 path $.entities[5]

for you trailing "emptiness" JSON document. There is no way to check if the next JSON token would fail or not according to the lenient mode in Gson. Not the best per se (but probably the only way) is using reflection in order to get the `JsonReader` backing reader (`Reader` actually) and decorating it with a new `JsonReader` overriding `hasNext()` method or something like that. It would be nice if `JsonReader` would support a method to check if its last value was generated because of the lenient mode set to true. But even if it supported something like that, there would be no guarantee to remove the last element because a particular type adapter might return a non-modifiable collection.

By the way, I think this issue should be posted to https://github.com/google/gson/issues/ -- I'd love to get the Gson team feedback.

Comment: Thanks for the such a detailed explanation. I will try the above solution, meanwhile I have created raised the concern on their github page [Github](https://github.com/google/gson/issues/1081)